# Inside a PDF, I want to use javascript to Fetch the Host Name from Browser URL

Tags: javascript, pdf, url, adobe, hostname

I have a PDF, I always open in it a Web browser from a tool called ServiceNow. When the PDF loads in the Browser, the URL of the PDF is of the below format

`https://test.service-now.com/sys_attachment.do?sysparm_referring_url=tear_off&view=true&sys_id=testValue`

Now, my PDF has a hyperlink, The goal is to make this hyperlink address dynamic. To make it Dynamic, I need to fetch the hostName from the browser URL, which is test.service-now.com

I have a method to open the hyperlink in the new Tab, for which I have used `app.launchURL(targetUrl,true);`

But I don't know if there is any method that i can use in PDF scripting to fetch the hostname from browser URL.

Below is what I tried to put in the Run a Javascript Action for the PDF HyperLink.

```
var domain = location.hostname;// This is wrong - need to know what I can use here

var targetUrl = domain+"/sys_attachment.do?sysparm_referring_url=tear_off&view=true&sys_id=testValue";

app.launchURL(targetUrl,true);
```

Comment: You could always get the window.location object, and then just substr it to change the end of it.

Comment: Can't you use relative links inside the PDF?

Comment: @FeaturedSpace, we cannot use windows object in a PDF scripting. That's where am stuck.

Comment: @James I dont think so

Comment: I think you should [check](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1697460)